# django access request data (without POST or GET )

Tags: django, post, get, request

Is there any way to access the request data without specifying the request method - GET or POST ?
I have a class based view which uses POST with some parameters.
Sometimes for some tests/debugging I want to use this view with a GET method, but then I need to change all the parameters to `request.GET` instead of `request.POST`.
Since my view is class based, I've already specify the method in the class by choosing post/get method. So I would prefer to access both GET and POST data together.

Comment: There are tools out there that make it easy to debug using POSTs, just for one example the Postman chrome app.

Answer (score 3):

No, Django does not provide a way to do this. It once had a `request.REQUEST` attribute, but it was deprecated in Django 1.7 and removed in Django 1.9.

It was removed because there was consensus that treating `request.GET` and `request.POST` the same was not a good idea. See the [mailing list discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/m/#!topic/django-developers/yw7OPb_O0QA/discussion) for more info.

Comment: Too bad. I do think it is a useful attribute when using class based views, where the method is already specified on the class. (by overriding post or get method in the class)